# When speaking “I feel like ...” , where to pause?

Tags: spoken-english, rhythm

> Surrounded by the majestic mountains, breathtaking coastlines, and enjoying a warm, mild climate, I often **feel like** I’m residing in paradise on earth.

When reading the last part of the sentence, should I pause after like, or between feel and like? A retired American did the later, but I remember hearing younger ones did the former. If both are normal, when would you do which?

Comment: [did the latter, two t's]. You can pause in speech anywhere you want to. There is no rule for that.

Comment: @Lambie Welllll, some pauses make you sound like William Shatner. And of course some can alter meaning a bit.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't take much pause in either spot; mainly just where we see commas. Also (off-topic) there's some non-parallel construction in the first part of the sentence: "Surrounded by mountains, coastlines, and enjoying."

Comment: @AndyBonner i didn't write it

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're hearing two different uses of the word *like* that would both work in the sentence you reference.

There has been much discussion ([example](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-so-many-otherwise-intelligent-millennials-have-a-tendency-to-overuse-the-word-%E2%80%9Clike%E2%80%9D-Do-they-even-realize-how-inane-it-sounds#:%7E:text=Because%2C%20like%2C%20you%20can%20put,about%20your%20choice%20of%20words.)) of younger people using *like* as a discourse marker. Using like almost as punctuation in its own right.

> He's like pausing for thought so like he can think of something like clever to say.

As an well-aged, native UK English speaker I would use like in conjunction with feel

> I feel like a plate of the Earth in motion (Al Stewart)

The two uses of like would result in the different pauses you notice. Those who don't like like like as like a discourse marker, really don't like it and seem to think less of people who like use like that way. You might consider your audience and the impression you want to give before using like.

Comment: Thanks. I can't open quora till I get help to climb over GFW.

Comment: Google "millennials use like" for many other discussions

Comment: Thanks. Same with Google.

Comment: Example: Why do a lot of people overuse the word 'like' in their sentences? For example, “I'm gonna, like, go to the mall today to buy some, like, shoes and shirts”.
The use of “like,” as you describe it, is verbal clutter, along the same lines as “um” or “ya know.” It’s simply habitual. Most people are barely aware that they’re saying it. From what I can tell, the trend became ubiquitous in the 1980s with the popularity of Moon Unit Zappa’s song “Valley Girl.”

Answer (score 1):

You might pause after **I feel**  when you're searching for words to describe how you feel. Otherwise there's no significant pause between the two words **feel** and **like** --  just enough so that the words are distinct. The above is true with also with respect to any pause after **like**.  If you're searching for words, you can pause after **like**, otherwise **like I'm** are said with just the normal word-separation pause, not a marked syntactic pause.

Answer (score 1):

Pauses, like intonation, in English, *can be complicated*. But there is no rule about where one pauses **unless** directed by your public speaking or acting coach/director who are telling you to pause here or there for the effect they feel they want to achieve.

- I feel like [pause] I'm living in paradise on earth.

> OR

- I feel [pause] like I'm living in paradise on earth.

If I were **reading** this, *I would not pause at all*.

If you are reading it, *knowing its coming* and want to stress the fact of what you feel, *stop after feel*. If you want to *stress the simile* (comparison using like here), pause after like.